# Laravel - POST date as JSON and save as DATE Constraint in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, laravel-5.7

#### Problem Statement:

I've defined `DATE` format in MySQL Column DataType Constraint database.

However, While sending Date in JSON object in [`ISO`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) format where it must be `DATE` *DataType* in MySQL Constraint using Laravel [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment) and [all input data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input)

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '1990-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' for column 'date_of_birth' at row 1
```

---

#### Files & Configuration:

Blade file

```
<input type="date" id="date_of_birth">

<script> 
    var dob = new Date( $("#date_of_birth").val() ).toISOString();
</script>
```

Post JSON object

```
{
    date_of_birth: "1990-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Setting attribute for Mass Assignment

`App\Models\User.php`

```
protected $fillable = [ 'date_of_birth' ]
```

`App\Http\Controllers\UpdateController.php`

```
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {

        $id = $user->updateOrCreate($request->all());
```

Comment: **Invalid datetime format**, so, what date format have you defined there? In database for date column **date_of_birth**.

Comment: I have defined `DATE` format in database.

Comment: It's not a date format. It's a datatype.

Comment: You should use a mutator (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).

Comment: Read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html) and don't mess **datetype** with **date format**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to give credit [@Armagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997849/armage). Using [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Set the user's date_of_birth.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = Carbon::parse($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the tip to use Mutators from [@Armagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997849/armage) -
for dates there is [this simplified magic `Date Mutators`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators):
`App\Models\User.php`

```php
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'date_of_birth',
    ];
}
```

you just have to add your attribute to this list and Laravel does the *Carbon* thing for you. :-)